# why is synchronised method not working?

Tags: java, multithreading

i was working with the synchronized statement and made the following program...synchronized the runn class with this as object reference ..bt smhw the desired output is nt there....

```
class runn extends Thread {
    String s;

    runn(String a) {
        s=a;
        start();
    }

     public void show() {
        System.out.print("["+s);
        try {
            sleep(50);
        } catch(Exception a){}

        System.out.print("]");
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            show();
        }
    }
}

public class multi4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        new runn("hello ");
        new runn("this is ");
        new runn("multithreading");
    }
}
```

The output should be :

```
[hello][this is][multithreading]
```

but synchronisation is not working smhw

Please help.

Comment: "somehow" is not spelt "smhw". Please don't leave out vowels unless your keyboard is broken.

Comment: Do not synchronize on `this` because each thread has its own instance so you are achieving nothing. You must synchronize on one and the same instance from all threads.

Comment: will keep that in mind :P
now will you help me with the problem ??

Comment: You are also wrong in assuming that synchronization will give you sequencing guarantees. If it did, it would be a useless feature.

Comment: It's also very bad form to start a thread it's constructor.

Comment: @nneonneo care to elaborate?

Comment: @user2737412: read his reply more carefully. If you don't get it, [learn more about `synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: but isn't the job of synchronization to make sure that one thread completes and only then the others resume ..(on a particular method)

Comment: While we're at it, it is also bad to extend the Thread class at all

Comment: It is _beter_ to implement Runnable than extend Thread, yes @MarkoTopolnik.

Comment: @user2737412: Nope, that's not at all what `synchronized` is for.

Comment: @user2737412: while we're at it, please can you fix your question to include vowels?

Comment: The job of synchronization is preventing simultaneous execution. The order in which you execute the start method has no consequences on the actual order of acquiring the lock.

Comment: yea bt if one thread does acquire the lock then its bound to complete if synchronized... like [hello] should be printed after that this is or multithreading , both can b printed ..depending on who gets the lock first..

Comment: one last question - doesn't join() do the same thing.. then wat was the need fr synchronization ??

Comment: join is a much blunter tool than synchronized. Normally you don't synchronize the entire run method of a thread, you use finer granularity. It is your specific use case which would be better served by join. Then again, why use threads in the first place if you force sequencing on them?

Comment: Multithreading is a pretty complex topic, and I can't imagine learning it meaningfully from ad-hoc questions on SO. I highly recommend reading a book that teaches it comprehensively; I found Java Concurrency In Practice to be quite good.

Comment: Please don't use abbreviated language. For English non-natives it can be confusing. And for natives it can be disturbing. Just basic net etiquette.

Comment: but for young guys like me its time saving ..heheh.. (jk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes:

- You `synchronized` on the individual `runn` objects. This has no effect because each thread uses a different synchronization object.
- The `synchronized` keyword does not magically cause threads to run in order. It merely prevents threads from attempting to execute the `synchronized` block at the same time, *if you synchronize on the same object*. They may still run in any order, but wouldn't be able to *interleave* their output. That is, if you `synchronized` on a shared object, you could get e.g. `[this is][hello][multithreading]`, but not `[this is[hello][multithreading]]`.

Comment: wait i think i got the hang of this...lemme just work up a quick sol

Comment: done .thanks ya'll... i passed the object on which i wanted to call the synchronized function...it worked..cuz objects are passed by reference :D again thanks